# What could be preventing my garage door from shutting?

Tags: garage-door-opener

To shut the door I have to push the wall control twice, then hold it in until the door completely closes.  Usually about half way down it still stops and begins to open again.  The garage door opener is approx. two years old Craftsman, 1/2 HP.

Comment: Garage doors retract automatically for a safety reasons.  I would check your sensors and make sure they're not unpluged, faulty, or out of line.

Answer (score 5):

Check your sensors. The sensors could also be very dirty or blocked by something.

Openers also often have cutout sensors that will stop the drive when the load gets too high on the motor. It may be that the load in your case may be too high due to wear, dragging rollers, bent track, lack of lubrication, or rusty chain/screw. Look for these things and correct if possible.

The overload cutout sensors are often adjustable and may be set to low and thus need re-adjustment.

Comment: You may also want to consider this: some evenings during specific days each summer, our garage door won't close. Turns out the sun burns a little bit too bright for the sensor's liking. A shadow covering the sensor is generally enough to make the problem go away.

Comment: Flood damage killed ours once.We also need to adjust them about every year, something will knock them or spider web get too thick over them.